# How to write stream on Amazon S3 using Structured Streaming Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I don't receive data into my s3 bucket and I don't receive any error. I'm working with Spark 2.3.0 and python. Basically, I'm trying to make a Datalake extracting data from Kafka using Structured Streaming Spark and I would like to write the stream into S3 bucket, but I can't. I would like to know how to do it. My main idea is the following:

```
query = self.query_impressions \
        .writeStream \
        .format("parquet") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", self.join_path + "/applicationHistory").partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour") \
        .option("path", "s3a://datalake/test")
```

I don't know if I need to use some packages, configurations, permissions or others things. I have these configurations:

```
import os
import time
import subprocess
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true \ 
  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key="xxx" \ 
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key="yyy" \
  pyspark-shell'
```

Comment: _I would like to write the stream into S3 bucket, but I can't_ - it sounds like you experience some problems. Please provide enough details (tracebacks, error messages, description of the symptoms)

Comment: I don't receive data into my s3 bucket, I can keep all the data into local folders but when I try to do the same on s3 I just not receive data. I think is some related to the permissions between the EC2 machine that I'm using and the s3 bucket, or I need to add some parameters when I run the code, or I'm not using the correct syntax or others. I would like to have an example of storing data into s3 using writeStream of Structured Streaming.